# Why is it easier to estimate $P(X|Y)$ rather than $P(Y|X)$ in terms of number of parameters?

Tags: probability, bayesian, estimation, parameterization

In chapter 3 of the book by Mitchell ("[Generative and discriminative classifiers: Naive Bayes and logistic regression](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/mlbook/NBayesLogReg.pdf)") he states that "accurately estimating P(X|Y)
typically requires many more examples. To see why, consider the number of parameters
we must estimate when Y is boolean and X is a vector of n boolean
attributes. In this case, we need to estimate a set of parameters

$\theta_{ij} \equiv P(X=x_i|Y=y_i)$

where the index $i$ takes on $2^n$ possible values (one for each of the possible vector
values of $X$), and $j$ takes on $2$ possible values. Therefore, we will need to estimate
approximately $2^{n+1}$ parameters."

Is that meaning it is needed to find a parameter for each probability for each possible combination of $X$ and $Y$? Given I've done that, how to put all together?

Answer (score 0):

The author compares $P(Y)$ (not $P(Y|X)$) and $P(X|Y)$ in terms of estimation complexity, due to the quickly growing $2^n$ term wrt number of dimensions. This is because of the dependence modelling in the joint distribution. Naive Bayes uses conditional independence assumption and relaxes this to $2n$ terms.

Comment: I'm not getting where that $2^n$ comes from. Is that due to the law of total probability?

Comment: when X is boolean with dimension n, there are $2^n$ different possibilities for it.